Angular 18 - CKEditor implementation with ssr
Im trying to implement CKEditor wtih angular 18 SSR.
import { afterNextRender, Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CKEditorModule } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-editor',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, CKEditorModule],
  templateUrl: './editor.component.html',
  styleUrl: './editor.component.css',
})
export class EditorComponent {
  editor: any = null;
  config: any;

  constructor() {
    afterNextRender(() => {
      this.loadCkEditor();
    });
  }

  async loadCkEditor() {
    const { Bold, Essentials, Italic, Mention, Paragraph, Undo } = await import(
      'ckeditor5'
    );
    this.config = {
      toolbar: ['undo', 'redo', '|', 'bold', 'italic'],
      plugins: [Bold, Essentials, Italic, Mention, Paragraph, Undo],
    };
    this.editor = (await import('ckeditor5')).ClassicEditor.create(
      document.querySelector('#editor') as any,
      this.config,
    );
  }
}
<div id="editor"></div>

Seems like component is working but css is not loaded. Not sure how to fix it or if there is better way to load this component. Or maybe even use different rich text editor that would be simpler to implement wth Angular ssr. Please help, thanks

Please [edit] your question title to describe the problem you're having or question you're asking. Your current title is just the useless repetition of the tags (which should not be in the title at all). The title should be clear and descriptive enough that a future site user skimming a list of search results will know what it contains. For suggestions on writing a good title, see [ask].

I think you missed to import the CSS, that may have been the issue.
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ClassicEditor, Bold, Essentials, Italic, Mention, Paragraph, Undo } from 'ckeditor5';
import { SlashCommand } from 'ckeditor5-premium-features';

import 'ckeditor5/ckeditor5.css';
import 'ckeditor5-premium-features/ckeditor5-premium-features.css';

@Component( {
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
} )

Official Getting Started Guide

I also think you might have missed importing the CKEditor CSS into your project. To resolve this, you can include the CKEditor styles in your global SCSS file. For example, in my global.scss, I added the following:
// global.scss
@import 'ckeditor5/ckeditor5.css';

You’ll also need to make sure that your angular.json is properly configured to include your global SCSS file. Here's my configuration for reference:
// angular.json
"architect": {
  "build": {
    "options": {
      "styles": ["src/content/scss/global.scss", /* other global scss files */]
    }
  }
}


Besides, Since you're using Angular, I would recommend installing @ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular, which is specifically designed for seamless integration with Angular. This will simplify the setup process and ensure better compatibility, especially with SSR.
You can install the package using:
npm install @ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular

For detailed instructions, you can refer to the official documentation: CKEditor 5 with Angular Installation.
Here’s how I successfully set it up in my project.
Component HTML:
<!-- xxx.component.html -->
@if (editor && config) {
  <ckeditor ngSkipHydration [editor]="editor" [config]="config" data="<p>Hello, world!</p>"></ckeditor>
}

Component TypeScript:
// xxx.component.ts
import { afterNextRender, ChangeDetectorRef, Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CKEditorModule } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular';
import { ClassicEditor } from 'ckeditor5';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-xxx',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CKEditorModule],
  templateUrl: './xxx.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./xxx.component.scss'],
})
export class HomeComponent {
  editor: typeof ClassicEditor | null = null;
  config: typeof ClassicEditor.defaultConfig | null = null;

  constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    afterNextRender(() => {
      this.loadCkEditor();
    });
  }

  async loadCkEditor() {
    const { Bold, Essentials, Italic, Mention, Paragraph, Undo, ClassicEditor, Heading } = await import('ckeditor5');
    this.config = {
      toolbar: ['undo', 'redo', '|', 'bold', 'italic'],
      plugins: [Bold, Essentials, Italic, Mention, Paragraph, Undo]
      },
    };
    this.editor = ClassicEditor;
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
  }
}

